# three.js raycaster is selecting all objects behind and in front of the object I want to select

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a 3d model(.obj) of a house that is being rendered using 3js. The raycaster in my code is working but I am having an issue of it selecting every object behind and in front of the object I am trying to select. I only want to return the name of the object I select instead. Any help would be appreciated. Currently I'm just having the name of the object getting sent to the console for now.

```
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
  const renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});      
  var kitchenCameraActive = false;
  document.getElementById("roomSelect").addEventListener("change", changeIt);

function changeIt(e) {
    //e.target.value
    document.getElementById(e.target.value).click();
    console.log(e);
}

  var fov = 45;
  var aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  var near = 0.1;
  var far = 100;
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(-97.570, 5.878, -5.289);
  camera.rotation.set(0,0,0);   
  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
  controls.update();

  document.getElementById("kitchen").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);         
  document.getElementById("bathroom").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);        
  document.getElementById("deck").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);        
  document.getElementById("livingRoom").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);        
  document.getElementById("bedRoom").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);
  document.getElementById("walkway").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);
  document.getElementById("sideHouse").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);
  document.getElementById("frontPorch").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);
  document.getElementById("garageDoor").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);
  document.getElementById("insideGarage").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);

function changeCamera(e) {       
    camera.rotation.set(e.toElement.attributes[5].nodeValue, e.toElement.attributes[6].nodeValue, e.toElement.attributes[7].nodeValue);     
    camera.fov = e.toElement.attributes[4].nodeValue;
    camera.position.set(e.toElement.attributes[1].nodeValue, e.toElement.attributes[2].nodeValue, e.toElement.attributes[3].nodeValue);     
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    if (e.target.id == "walkway" || e.target.id == "frontPorch" || e.target.id == "garageDoor" || e.target.id == "insideGarage")
        {
            controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
            controls.update();
        }

    //controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
    //controls.update();    
    //controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI/2;
    //controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI/2;
    console.log(e);
    //controls.enabled = false;                                 
  }

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');
  {
    const planeSize = 40;

  }

    function frameArea(sizeToFitOnScreen, boxSize, boxCenter, camera) {
    const halfSizeToFitOnScreen = sizeToFitOnScreen * 0.5;
    const halfFovY = THREE.Math.degToRad(camera.fov * .5);
    const distance = halfSizeToFitOnScreen / Math.tan(halfFovY);
    // compute a unit vector that points in the direction the camera is now
    // in the xz plane from the center of the box
    const direction = (new THREE.Vector3()).subVectors(camera.position, boxCenter).multiply(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalize();
    // move the camera to a position distance units way from the center
    // in whatever direction the camera was from the center already
    camera.position.copy(direction.multiplyScalar(distance).add(boxCenter));
    // pick some near and far values for the frustum that
    // will contain the box.
    camera.near = boxSize / 100;
    camera.far = boxSize * 100;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    // point the camera to look at the center of the box
    camera.lookAt(boxCenter.x, boxCenter.y, boxCenter.z);
  }

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
// load a resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'dapHouseGood5.obj',
    // called when resource is loaded
    function ( object ) {
        scene.add( object );
    },
    // called when loading is in progresses
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function ( error ) {
        console.log( 'An error happened' );
    });

function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

function render() {
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);                   
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

    function onPositionChange(o) {
    console.log("position changed in object");
    console.log(o);
    }
    controls.addEventListener('change', onPositionChange);

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var raycaster, mouse = { x : 0, y : 0};
init();

function init () {
    //Usual setup code here.
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'click', raycast, false );
    //Next setup code there.
}

function raycast ( e ) {
    //1. sets the mouse position with a coordinate system where the center
    //   of the screen is the origin
    mouse.x = ( e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    //2. set the picking ray from the camera position and mouse coordinates
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    //var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,   -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
    //raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse3D, camera );       

    //3. compute intersections
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );

    for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
        //console.log( intersects[ i ].object.id );
        console.log( intersects[ i ].object.name );
        //console.log( intersects[ i ] );
    }
}
```

}

```
main();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, recursive = true )` call returns intersections against all of the objects you provide, and their children. If you only want to find intersections on a specific object, only include that object when calling `intersectObjects`. This will improve performance, as well.

If you don't know which object you want, the intersection results are returned sorted by distance. The closest object is first, and you can just use that.

See: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster

Comment: Thanks you for the clarification